# I have a problem with my "Game of life" on python

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know why but my "def" that checks 3 rules of "Game of live" doesn't work correctly. I have 2 lists that contains 0 and some 1 to check the program. [3 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIU8H.png) that should give this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AUhW.png) but instead it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuZV8.png)

```py
def upd(mass,screen,WHITE,mass1):
    BLACK = (0,0,0)
    for i in range(len(mass)-1):
        for j in range(len(mass[i])-1):
            if mass[i][j] == 0:
                if near(mass,i,j) == True:
                    mass1[i][j]=1
                    print("case1")
            if mass[i][j] == 1:
                if (near(mass,i,j)==False):
                    mass1[i][j]=0
                    print("case 2")
                if (near(mass,i,j)==False):
                    mass1[i][j]=0
                    print("case 3")
    for i in range(len(mass1)-1):
        for j in range(len(mass1[i])-1):
            if mass1[i][j] == 1:
                p.draw.rect(screen, (WHITE), Rect((j*10,i*10), (10,10)))
            else:
                p.draw.rect(screen, (BLACK), Rect((j*10,i*10), (10,10)))
    mass=mass1
```

```py
def near(mass,i,j):
    counter = 0
    if mass[i][j+1]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i][j-1]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i+1][j]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i-1][j]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i+1][j+1]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i-1][j+1]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i+1][j-1]==1:
        counter+=1
    if mass[i-1][j-1] == 1:
        counter+=1
    if counter<2 or counter == 0:
        return False
    if counter > 3:
        return False
    if counter == 3:
        return True
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww1W7.png) that repeats every circle

I am not good in python so I think this code is quite scarry:)
I'll be very grateful for any advice

Comment: There is another rule, if ```no.of.neibours==2``` then the cell survives to next iteration but i can't able to see that condition in your function ```near()```

Comment: @Hariharan In that case, it just exists in "mass" and nothing changes

Comment: @Rabbid76 I should try this, ty

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have 2 lists "mass" and "mass1", mass for checking and drawing and mass1 that contains new values and after the circle "mass" takes "mass1" values

Comment: @Rabbid76 I changed that mass1 for counting neighbors, and it works.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mass = mass1` does not copy the contents of the grid, it just puts a reference to `mass1` in `mass` (actually only in the local variable `mass` in scope of `upd`). You must deep copy the grid:

```py
for i in range(len(mass1)):
    for j in range(len(mass1[i])):
        mass[i][j] == mass1[i][j]
```